# Zapier Code (JS) + Twitter API - POST statuses/update (in_reply_to_status_id)

Tags: javascript, twitter, zapier

What I'm trying to achieve is a Zapier Code (JS) action to preform a Twitter reply to a given status ID with a given text .

I'm already using the functioning Zapier (JS) Code action offered by [@KayCee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3514632/kaycee) which preform a `POST favorites/create` and would like to modify it so it would preform a `reply` action to any given `status_id` using the `POST statuses/update (in_reply_to_status_id)` as instructed by [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update.html).

Here is @KayCee's code with the modifications I made to preform a reply:

```
// This code requires that you set the ID of the tweet that you want to reply to as an input variable called "reply_to_id" and the text you wish to reply as an input variable called "status_text". Learn more at https://zapier.com/help/code/#data-variables


// INSTUCTIONS FOR SETTING THESE REQUIRED VARIABLES: After you create a new app at https://apps.twitter.com/, click on the name of the app to open it. Then, select the "Keys and Access Tokens" tab.
var twitterApplicationConsumerKey = 'CONSUMERKEY';
var twitterApplicationConsumerSecret = 'CONSUMERSECRET';
var twitterApplicationAccessToken = 'ACCESSTOKEN';
var twitterApplicationAccessTokenSecret = 'ACCESSTOKENSECRET'; 

// That's it. No need to edit anything below.

function b64_hmac_sha1(k,d,_p,_z){
  if(!_p){_p='=';}if(!_z){_z=8;}function _f(t,b,c,d){if(t<20){return(b&c)|((~b)&d);}if(t<40){return b^c^d;}if(t<60){return(b&c)|(b&d)|(c&d);}return b^c^d;}function _k(t){return(t<20)?1518500249:(t<40)?1859775393:(t<60)?-1894007588:-899497514;}function _s(x,y){var l=(x&0xFFFF)+(y&0xFFFF),m=(x>>16)+(y>>16)+(l>>16);return(m<<16)|(l&0xFFFF);}function _r(n,c){return(n<<c)|(n>>>(32-c));}function _c(x,l){x[l>>5]|=0x80<<(24-l%32);x[((l+64>>9)<<4)+15]=l;var w=[80],a=1732584193,b=-271733879,c=-1732584194,d=271733878,e=-1009589776;for(var i=0;i<x.length;i+=16){var o=a,p=b,q=c,r=d,s=e;for(var j=0;j<80;j++){if(j<16){w[j]=x[i+j];}else{w[j]=_r(w[j-3]^w[j-8]^w[j-14]^w[j-16],1);}var t=_s(_s(_r(a,5),_f(j,b,c,d)),_s(_s(e,w[j]),_k(j)));e=d;d=c;c=_r(b,30);b=a;a=t;}a=_s(a,o);b=_s(b,p);c=_s(c,q);d=_s(d,r);e=_s(e,s);}return[a,b,c,d,e];}function _b(s){var b=[],m=(1<<_z)-1;for(var i=0;i<s.length*_z;i+=_z){b[i>>5]|=(s.charCodeAt(i/8)&m)<<(32-_z-i%32);}return b;}function _h(k,d){var b=_b(k);if(b.length>16){b=_c(b,k.length*_z);}var p=[16],o=[16];for(var i=0;i<16;i++){p[i]=b[i]^0x36363636;o[i]=b[i]^0x5C5C5C5C;}var h=_c(p.concat(_b(d)),512+d.length*_z);return _c(o.concat(h),512+160);}function _n(b){var t="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/",s='';for(var i=0;i<b.length*4;i+=3){var r=(((b[i>>2]>>8*(3-i%4))&0xFF)<<16)|(((b[i+1>>2]>>8*(3-(i+1)%4))&0xFF)<<8)|((b[i+2>>2]>>8*(3-(i+2)%4))&0xFF);for(var j=0;j<4;j++){if(i*8+j*6>b.length*32){s+=_p;}else{s+=t.charAt((r>>6*(3-j))&0x3F);}}}return s;}function _x(k,d){return _n(_h(k,d));}return _x(k,d);
}

var replyToId = input.reply_to_id;
var status = input.status_text;

//create nonce
function generateRandomString(desiredLengthOfRandomString) {
    var result = '';
    var possibleCharactersForRandomString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < desiredLengthOfRandomString; i++ )
        result += possibleCharactersForRandomString.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleCharactersForRandomString.length));

    return result;
}

var randomString = generateRandomString(32);
var nonce = new Buffer(randomString).toString('base64');


//create timestamp
var timestamp = Math.floor(new Date() / 1000);

//create the signature
var signatureParameterString = 'in_reply_to_status_id=' + replyToId + '&status=' + status + '&oauth_consumer_key=' + twitterApplicationConsumerKey + '&oauth_nonce=' + encodeURIComponent(nonce) + '&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=' + timestamp + '&oauth_token=' + twitterApplicationAccessToken + '&oauth_version=1.0';

var signatureBaseString = 'POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate.json&' + encodeURIComponent(signatureParameterString);

var signingKey = encodeURIComponent(twitterApplicationConsumerSecret) + '&' + encodeURIComponent(twitterApplicationAccessTokenSecret);

var signature = b64_hmac_sha1(signingKey, signatureBaseString);

var apiUrl = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?in_reply_to_status_id=' + replyToId + '&status=' + status;

var oauthString = 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="' + twitterApplicationConsumerKey + '", oauth_nonce="' + encodeURIComponent(nonce) + '", oauth_signature="' + encodeURIComponent(signature) + '", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="' + timestamp + '", oauth_token="' + twitterApplicationAccessToken + '", oauth_version="1.0"';

fetch(apiUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': oauthString
  }
})
.then(function(res) {
  return res.json();
})
.then(function(body) {
  var output = body;
  callback(null, output);
})
.catch(callback);
```

For some reason, I keep on getting error message: "Could not authenticate you" although the same code worked for performing a "like".

Not sure what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest to use the twit module : https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit

Comment: The Zapier Tweet module is **only** capable of creating a _new tweet_ but not a _reply tweet_ using the `in_reply_to_status_id` parameter of Twitter API. That means the new tweet that will be created will be standing on its own and not be treated as a reply to a specific designated tweet and not be part of the conversation. Using Zapier's `New Tweet` action can, at best, mention the @username of the person authoring the tweet I'd like to reply to, but this mentioning tweet will not be counted in the reply chain of the original tweet.

Comment: is the twitterApplicationConsumerKey and the following three vars supposed to be completely private? Not familiar with the Twitter API, but it looks like something that shouldn't be exposed

Comment: Indeed the Twitter 'CONSUMERKEY', 'CONSUMERSECRET', 'ACCESSTOKEN' and 'ACCESSTOKENSECRET' are private tokens corresponding with my own app on my own twitter account... these are easily generated here: [https://apps.twitter.com](https://apps.twitter.com)

Comment: @EladRatson If it's very private, I highly recommend mod flagging your own question and asking to have it redacted. The revision history still contains the tokens. I'd also recommend generating new ones and revoking access to the old ones, assuming you can.

Comment: Thank you @Zoe... will follow your recommendations